# Handle Click Event for LinkButton in User Control from Parent ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have a LinkButton within a User Control and it has handled with:

```
Private Sub LoginLinkLinkButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LoginLinkLinkButton.Click
        Response.Redirect("/", True)
End Sub
```

On certain ASPX pages I would like to handle the click from the page's code behind, opposed to within the user control. How do I override the handle within the control from the parent's code behind page?

**Update:**
Based on the answer, I have the updated the User Control:

```
Public Event LoginLinkClicked As OnLoginClickHandler
Public Delegate Sub OnLoginClickHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

[...]

Private Sub LoginLinkLinkButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LoginLinkLinkButton.Click
        **If OnLoginClickHandler IsNot Nothing Then**
            RaiseEvent LoginLinkClicked(Me, e)
        Else
            Response.Redirect("/", True)
        End If
End Sub
```

The problem is determining the correct syntax for the if line because the above is invalid.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible or not, but you could certainly consider separating the logic into a central class which both you ASPX and ASCX event handlers call.

Comment: I updated my answer. Is that a valid translation for your update?

Comment: I'm not sure that will help, basically I want to define a default behavior, and on a few pages override the default behavior. It boils down to finding a way to query if an handler has subscribers in VB.NET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to expose a new event from the user control. Apologies as the following code is all in ***C#*** and it's been a long time since I touched VB.Net, but you should get the idea:

You can use a delegate event by adding the following to your `UserControl`:

```
public event OnLoginClickHandler LoginClick;
public delegate void OnLoginClickHandler (object sender, EventArgs e);
```

Then call the following to your LinkButton `Click` event:

```
protected void LoginLinkLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Only fire the event if there's a subscriber
    if (OnLoginClickHandler != null) 
    {
        OnLoginClickHandler(sender, e); 
    }
    else
    {
        // Not handled, so perform the standard redirect
        Response.Redirect("/", true);
    }
}
```

You can then just hook up into this within your aspx markup:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="Foo" OnLoginClick="Foo_LoginClick" />
```

And your server side event handler on your **Page** will be as follows:

```
protected void Foo_LoginClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // This event was fired from the UserControl
}
```

**UPDATE**

I think this is how you translate the event subscription check to VB.Net:

```
If LoginClick IsNot Nothing Then
    RaiseEvent LoginClick(sender, e) 
End If
```

Comment: Good solution. I'm having trouble translating if (OnLoginClickHandler != null)  
    { 
        OnLoginClickHandler(sender, e);  
    } 

I'll post what I have in the question.

Comment: That creates the following error: 'OnLoginClickHandler' is a type and cannot be used as an expression.

Comment: I tried that as well and received this error: 'Public Event LoginClick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.

Comment: @Josh - Updated again. I missed the `RaiseEvent` call.

Comment: The problem is that you cannot test LoginClick for Nothing. Based on research it looks like VB.NET doesn't expose the subscribers as easily C#. Being crunched for time I had implement without a default. I'll mark this as answered because you answered the main question about how to call an event from the parent page. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Josh - It should work. See this example here: http://www.cynotwhynot.com/blog/post/Dont-Blindly-Raise-Events-in-VBNET.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have a look into below code and links.

```
Parent Page aspx.cs part

public partial class getproductdetails : System.Web.UI.Page
{
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  Button btnYes = (Button)ucPrompt.FindControl("btnYes");
  btnYes.Click += new EventHandler(ucPrompt_btnYes_Click);
 }

 void ucPrompt_btnYes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    //Do Work
  }
}
```

***Read more details how it works (Reference) :-***

[Handle events of usercontrol in parent page in asp.net](http://www.dotnetbull.com/2013/03/handle-control-event-of-user-control-in.html)

[Calling a method of parent page from user control](http://www.dotnetbull.com/2013/03/calling-method-of-parent-page-from-user.html)